# Jquery flot and week numbers

Tags: jquery, graph, plot, flot, week-number

I made a page to plot average snowdepth by week number. Now that we entered 2010, week 1 my graph stretches the interval on the x-axis (yearweek). 
What I want is the weeknumber on the x-axis (51,52,1,2 etc), and a fixed intervalwidth. 
Anyone know how to do that?

[example](http://www.snowcams.eu/snowcondition/bardonecchia/105)

```
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

var d1 = [
[201001,118],[200952,112],[200951,102],[200950,97],[200949,93],
[200948,41],[200947,10],[200947,0]];

var d2 = [
[201001,33],[200952,31],[200951,31],[200950,25],[200949,23],
[200948,12],[200947,0],[200947,0]];

$.plot($("#placeholder"),
   [{data:d1,lines:{show: true},
     points:{show: true},label:"Mountain"},
    {data:d2,lines:{show: true},points:{show: true},label:"Valley"}],
    {xaxis: {tickSize:1, tickDecimals:0 }}
);

});
</script>
```

Comment: We're on week 53 of 2009/2010 right now, you can't jump over this week because not all years fit into exactly 52 weeks.

Comment: I know that it gives more details of things you can do with the X-Axis in the documentation, since I don't consider this an actual "answer" I'm putting it in the comments.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994796/jquery-flot-and-week-numbers I think.

Answer (score 3):

you could define a set of 'ticks' for the x-axis, and map your week numbers there

```
{xaxis: 
    {
        ticks: [[201001,'1'],[200952,'52'],[200951,'51'],....]
        tickSize:1, 
        tickDecimals:0
    }
}
```

V2 - seems to work, see the [flot chart](http://emeraldjava.blogspot.com/2010/01/flot-with-x-axis-ticks.html)

```
<div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div> 
<script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(function () {

var d1 = [
[200952,112],[200951,102],[200950,97],[200949,93],[200948,41],[200947,10],[200946,0]];

var d2 = [
[200952,31],[200951,31],[200950,25],[200949,23],[200948,12],[200947,0],[200946,0]];

$.plot($("#placeholder"),
   [{data:d1,lines:{show: true},
     points:{show: true},label:"Mountain"},
    {data:d2,lines:{show: true},points:{show: true},label:"Valley"}],
    {xaxis: {
        ticks: [[200952,'52'],[200951,'51'],[200950,'50'],[200949,'49'],[200948,'48'],[200947,'47'],[200946,'46']],
        tickSize:1, tickDecimals:1 }}
);

});
</script>
```

It seems '200947' is in your data set twice.

Comment: Would you have a look : http://www.sionvalais.com/snowcondition/les%202%20alpes/652
Can't get it to work. Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

try writing a function in tickformatter that will convert the straight set into week numbers.

for example:

```
xaxis: {        
    tickFormatter: function suffixFormatter(val, axis) {                
        return (val.toFixed(axis.tickDecimals) + 49) % 52;
    }
}
```

I have not tested this code, there may be some problems with type conversion.  It should take your set of (0, 1, 2, ...), and convert it to the new set (49, 50, 51, 52, 1, 2, ...), and so, when you plot your weeks, in your data, call week 49 0, and it will show up with a week.  For further flexibility, you can replace the return value with return '"week" + ((val.toFixed(axis.tickDecimals) + 49) % 52);' so that your ticks display 'week 1', 'week 2', etc.

See the flot api under 'Customizing the axes' for more info.